# How to auto accept terms while installing packages with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

While installing pkgs Ansible fails, because there is a need to accept licensing terms.

How to auto accept terms through `ansible-playbook`?

```
---
- hosts: client1
  remote_user: ansible
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: testing
      apt_repository: repo=ppa:webupd8team/java state=present
    - name: updating
      apt: update_cache=yes
    - name: installaing oracle pkg
      apt: pkg=oracle-java8-installer state=present update_cache=yes
```

Comment: The playbooks which utilize WebUpd8team PPA no longer work after Oracle changed their licensing scheme. See the following notice on the [WebUpd8team PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java):

"Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle). For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no universal method for "packages".

For Oracle Java add a task before calling `apt`:

```
- debconf:
    name: oracle-java8-installer
    question: shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1
    value: true
    vtype: select
```

Comment: How does one find the exact wording for the question, for each specific case?

Comment: Use `debconf-show <package>` on any Debian or derivative with the package installed to see questions/settings available.

Answer (score 2):

For virtualbox-ext-pack

```
- debconf:
    name: virtualbox-ext-pack
    question: virtualbox-ext-pack/license
    value: "true"
    vtype: select
```

before apt install command.

Comment: NOTE: `value: true` will NOT work! It should be strictly: `value: "true"`.